# One function to print vector and list in c++

Tags: c++, stl

While studying Standard Template Library

```
/*
Aim:Create a vector of integers. Copy it into a list, reversing as you 
do so.
*/

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<list>
using namespace std;
template<typename t>
void print(vector <t> &v)      //what changes need to be done here?
{
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    print(v);         
    list<int> l(v.size());
    reverse_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), l.begin());
    print(l);        //cannot call this
}
```

The problem is i want the same function `print()` to print the vector as well as the list for me.
I tried doing the following

```
void print(t <t> &v);
```

Can we do this? I have also seen the solutions using the ostream iterator 
for printing the containers.Would that be a solution to my problem?

Comment: You can do a more effective reversing of the elements using `std::reverse_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(l))`. This way there is no need to first create the list with default constructed objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to template your type vector or list. For instance the following works

```
template<typename Container>
void print(const Container& cont) {
   for (auto const& x : cont) {
      std::cout << x << " ";
   }
   std::cout << '\n';
}


int main() {
   std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};
   print(v);

   std::list<int> l(v.size());
   std::reverse_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), l.begin());
   print(l);
}
```

Output is

> 1 2 3 4
>
> 4 3 2 1

Comment: You may use `const auto&` if you referencece and do not change values in a range based for-loop

Comment: Yes you are right.  I just took the assumption that op only works with builtin types. For sake on genericty i ll edit that

Answer (score 8):

The correct way is to use an iterator:

```
template <class ForwardIter>
void print(ForwardIter begin, ForwardIter end)
{
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
        cout << *begin << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

This is how standard library functions are container-agnostic, and you should write functions this way too.

The reason for this is that iterators are really a general way to use something that can be iterated over. It could be vector, list, c array, file, socket, etc., and you don't need to know or care.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I believe it is better to use `std::copy`. The following code applies to arrays and lists as well as long as the container has a ForwardIterator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T>
void print(const T& v) {
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type>(std::cout, ", "));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> fiveInts = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    print(fiveInts);

    return 0;
}
```

If the code is used on a container don't support ForwardIterator, you will get a compilation error.

ps: thanks to Dieter and bipll, I changed my code. And yes, it is better to use iterators as params instead of the container itself.

Comment: `v[0]` requires a container with random access.

Comment: Like @DieterLücking noted, this should be good old `T::value_type` instead of `decltype`. Moreover, lets get rid of that trailing comma: `if(!v.empty()) { typename T::const_iterator e(v.end()); std::copy(v.begin(), --e, std::ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type>(std::cout, ", ")); std::cout << *e; }`

Comment: To lower requirements on T (e.g.: an array): `std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator<decltype(*std::begin(v))>(std::cout, ", "));`

Comment: @DieterLücking To be frank,at an intermediate programming level,i haven't got your concept exactly but will surely try to get it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to say your `print` function can handle anything:

```
template<typename t>
void print(t const &v) {
  // Same body
}
```

That will work, since iterating over any of the standard containers uses identical code.

But in a bigger program it could cause problems, because it won't work for anything that isn't a standard container. Ideally you would use some simple template metaprogramming to constrain it to types it works for (using e.g. `enable_if`).